# what is the best way to handle error in useMutation hook

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am using graphql to do my work, In one of my use-case I am using `useMutation hook` for doing mutation like add,insert or delete.

So here I have input field and button so on click I want to save data in db which is working fine,

**My main point is** what is the best way to handle the error in `react-apollo-graphql` in useMutation

currently I am handling the error using promises but I know that is not the best way to do that

**What I am doing is**

```
    const [createDep, {loading,error}] = useMutation(ADD_DEPARTMENTS,{  // here this error I want to do something here ton handle error and loading
    update(_,result){
   console.log(result)
    }
  })
const submitDepartment = (e) => { 
    let dept_name = e.department
    console.log(dept_name)
    createDep({
      variables: { dept_name },
    }).catch((res) => {   // I do not think This is the right way to do
      const errors = res.graphQLErrors.map((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });

    });
  };
```

Comment: You can either catch the error or provide an `onError` callback. See the linked post for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just wrapping it in a try / catch scope:

```
const [createDep] = useMutation(ADD_DEPARTMENTS, {     
  update(_,result){
    console.log(result)
  }
})

const submitDepartment = async (e) => { 
  let dept_name = e.department
  try {
    await createDep({variables: {dept_name}})
  } catch (err) {
    // handle error here
  }
};
```

Comment: hey react apollo  graphql gives this `{error}` object so what is the use of this then?

Comment: I edit the answer, I do not use the return {loading, error} of the mutation but generally the return of the promise and wrapping the whole try/catch.